# Как правильно обрабатывать запросы Telegram Bot API?

Tags: php

Пользователи пишут боту, бот отвечает на запросы отправляя текст из БД и файл через CurlFile.
Из-за многочисленных одновременно запросов к обработчику бота, бот перестает отвечать на любые запросы, глючит иногда.

Решил проблему следующим образом:
Для каждого запроса создаю отдельный процесс в консоле

```
exec('php ./bot.php &> /dev/null &');
```

Боюсь, что скоро сервер ляжет от многочисленных вызовов консоля через exec()

Так ли это? Большая ли нагрузка оказывает эта функция?
Если да, то каким еще образом можно решить данную проблему?